# compare after lower and trim df column in pyspark

Tags: dataframe

I want to compare dataframe column after trim and convert it into lower case in pyspark.
is below code is wrong ?

```
        if f.trim(Loc_Country_df.LOC_NAME.lower) == f.trim(sdf.location_name.lower):
            print('y')
        else:
            print('N')
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do like this because df columns are not just variable , they are collection of values(Iterable).

The best way is you can perform join.

```
 join_df=join_df.withColumn("LOC_NAME",trim(col("LOC_NAME")))

 sdf=sdf.withColumn("location_name",trim(col("location_name")))

join_df=Loc_Country_df.join(sdf,Loc_Country_df.LOC_NAME==sdf.location_name,"left")

from pyspark.sql import functions as f

join_df.withColumn('Result', f.when(f.col('LOC_NAME') == 0, "N").otherwise("Y")).show()
```